# CORS "It does not have HTTP ok status."

Tags: node.js, express

NodeJS Express platform. Using Zeit Now 2. Cannot use server.js as proxy to send from backend to prevent CORS. So, nor wrestling with CORS problems. Tested desktop: chrome, safari, firefox. Mobile: chrome, firefox. Have tested to host on Now with HTTPS, same error as I get locally on both `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000`, same using port `80`.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://**MY_URL**/user/login' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors to set my CORS configs:

```
app.use(cors({
  'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type', 'API-Key', 'API-Secret', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'', 'accept', 'client-security-token'],
  'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
  'origin': '*',
  'methods': 'GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  'preflightContinue': false,
  'credentials': true
}));
```

The CORS settings doesn't seem to work for my, so I tried with the `now.json` file, like this (trimmed veersion):

```
{
  "name": "my-test-api",
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    {
     "src": "/.*",
     "methods": ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
     "headers": { "Access-Control-Max-Age": "1000", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Accept": "text/plain", "Content-Type": "text/plain", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "sessionId, Content-Type, API-Key, API-Secret, Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "sessionId", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true" },
     "continue": true
    },
    { "src": "/user/login", "methods": ["POST"], "dest": "index.js" }
  ]
}
```

Even added statusCode 200 to all my responses, but without any success. Removing the Npm-cors-package won't change anything, but removing the Now.json totally destroys stuff, and I get [this error, from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) even though I have it specified in my `app.use(cors())`.

Not really sure what to do, have been struggeling with this forever. No problem with cURL or other hosts where I can use backend proxy.

Comment: Quotes are not balanced in `'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type', 'API-Key', 'API-Secret', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'', 'accept', 'client-security-token']`. Is that the problem, or is it just a typo in your question? In case of the latter, that makes me wonder how well your question represents your actual configuration.

Comment: You cannot set origin to a wildcard and include credentials! Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Comment: Have you tested using Postman?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to enable pre-flight requests for your route

```
app.use(cors())

app.options('/post/login', cors()) // enable pre-flight requests
app.post('/post/login', (req, res, next) => {
    // your code here
});
```

or for all routes

```
app.options('*', cors())
```

Comment: From chrome: "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: I get this in firefoz: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/… even though I specify the "origin" to "*" in cors()

Answer (score 3):

You can set the HTTP status of the pre-flight response.

```
app.options('*', function (req,res) { res.sendStatus(200); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this cryptic error when the preflight (OPTIONS) request returned a 404. I eventually found I was using an incorrect path, and my router (Golang httprouter) 404s OPTIONS for non-existent routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nginx's reverse proxy to proxy your 80 port's requests to 3000 port and it will  work fine

Answer (score 0):

Please try by adding one line and remove your old cors config from express and now.json

`app.use(cors());`

That’s it. CORS is now enabled.
If you make a request to your app, you will notice a new header being returned:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 0):

I use Nginx for cors configuration. But for local development in docker it's better to use express middleware:

```js
const corsMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range')
        .header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

```js
app.use(corsMiddleware);
```

Answer (score -1):

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/yoururl

Example:

```
axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/spo.handball4all.de/Spielbetrieb/index.php?orgGrpID=56&score=45991')
    .then(response => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
})
```